# Is that a serious bug?

Tags: myetherwallet, bug

I am trying to store and send some ERC20 tokens from myetherwallet.

1. My wallet does not show me the right balance of tokens.
2. When trying to send those tokens to another Ethereum address (that I specify), what is broadcasted to the blockchain is a tx to a different address.

---

I am getting 2 error messages:

1. > Transaction execution error

   (from MEW, but I am not prevented from generating and sending the tx)
2. > Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]

   (from Etherscan)

Comment: *"My wallet does not show me the right balance of tokens"* Their node was under a lot of strain yesterday, can you switch node in the top right and retry

Comment: *"When trying to send those tokens to another Ethereum address (that I specify), what is broadcasted to the blockchain is a tx to a different address"* What does the raw transaction say? Are you _certain_ you're on the legitimate MyEtherWallet[dot]com?

Comment: I changed the node to etherscan.io
Same result  --
For EOS (ERC20 token), it shows up twice with 2 different balances...

Comment: Yes, I am certain I am on the right MyEtherWallet[dot]com
raw tx:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x66c2f989238f468c18522ed8335699e67729d3f28a565716c900726c4d469802

Answer (score 1):

> My wallet does not show me the right balance of tokens

The MyEtherWallet node was under a lot of strain and it is advised to switch node in the top right. If you're just looking at your balances, use a block explorer so you don't expose your private keys.

- https://ethplorer.io
- https://etherscan.io

> When trying to send those tokens to another Ethereum address (that I specify), what is broadcasted to the blockchain is a tx to a different address...

This is because you make a transaction to the contract address and invoke a function `transfer()` which takes 2 parameters (the amount of tokens to transfer and the address to transfer to).

```
Function: transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) ***

MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
[0]:000000000000000000000000280c699961d44592c1655be22c272b4c0cfc4a06
[1]:00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004c4b40
```

The above tells the contract to transfer KC tokens to address 0x280c699961D44592C1655be22C272B4c0cFc4a06.

> "Transaction execution error"

This is a report that the transaction failed to complete - see below.

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]

This is because a condition in the contract did something to kill execution. Without reading the contract, I'm unsure what that is.

Comment: Thanks for your help --

Discussed with KC support team :
me: "Is that specific to kickico?"
KC team: "Yes. They are frozen till October 15Th It's written in a FAQ."